# Do I remove peers after a certain amount of time?(mainline dht)

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

I just finished implementing mainline dht with a flat based routing table. I recall from kademilia something about an updated peer list and efficient key republishing and I started to wonder if after a certain amount of time I should remove peers from peer lists. But I can't find anything in bep about it.

Comment: Are you asking about bittorrent peers (announce/get peers) or other dht nodes (routing table entries)?

Comment: Dht nodes I know are getting update checked via ping if they're 15 minutes old. I'm asking about BitTorrent peers. Qbittorrent seems to only send out 20 peers at most while my implementation has up to 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm asking about BitTorrent peers.

Yes, they should only be stored for a finite amount of time. The spec seems to be silent on that. [Libtorrent uses 45min timeout.](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/06f98369cb33bf652697a7f0c23b282ffd2b68b1/src/kademlia/dht_storage.cpp#L566)

> Qbittorrent seems to only send out 20 peers at most while my implementation has up to 300

It's probably only returning a sample of what it stores to keep UDP packet sizes below the link MTU.

Comment: I'm guessing this is fairly important and I should implement it. Weird how it's not specified it sounds fairly important.

Comment: Yeah, some BEPs are fairly minimal and leave a lot of details to the implementer. Which sortof works if the implementer is an experienced network engineer. Not so great for beginners.